# process cannot be disowned from shell in execute mode

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

It seems like many terminal emulators that offer an execute option, that is an option to open a new terminal running a particular command, do not allow processes to be disowned like when run normally. For example, I have bound a keyboard shortcut on my device to run a script in `termite`,

```sh
exec --no-startup-id termite --role floating_term --exec "bash /home/benjamin/scripts/search_open"
```

This script runs a fuzzy search tool in the terminal and then opens a subprocess,

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

path="$(find /home/benjamin/Documents /home/benjamin/Pictures /home/benjamin/Videos /home/benjamin/Desktop /home/benjamin/Downloads /home/benjamin/Music | fzf)"

if [ ! -z "$path" ]; then
    if [ -d "$path" ]; then
        nautilus $path > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    else
        ext="${path##*.}"
        case $ext in
            pdf )
                zathura $path > /dev/null 2>&1 &;;
            mp4 | mp3 | mkv ) 
                mpv $path > /dev/null 2>&1 &;;
            png | jpg )
                vimiv $path > /dev/null 2>&1 &;;
            * )
                grep -qI . $path || ! test -s $path && termite --exec "nvim $path" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
        esac
    fi
fi
```

The script appears to work correctly when run an open terminal (`./search_open`); a new window is opened and the terminal can be closed without closing the spawned process. However when spawned from a new terminal (`termite --exec`) the spawned window closes when the terminal closes. I have also tried using `nohup` and `disown` without any luck. I have verified this behavior with other terminal emulators, including alcritty and xfce-terminal.

Any clue as to what about the `exec` option on terminals prevents processes from being fully disowned or a way to work around its behavior?

Comment: Does it help if you redirect `/dev/null` to stdin too?

Comment: Great point, but no luck there. :(

Comment: Have you tried a double fork?

Comment: @tripleee How would a double fork look in a bash script?

Comment: `( subprocess & )` or even `(( subprocess & ))`

Comment: Hmmm, I tried `(command & < /dev/null > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)` and even `(setsid command < /dev/null > /dev/null 2> /dev/null) &` with still no luck.